# Using an ArcGIS Model Builder iterator to merge all shapefiles into one layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a GeoDatabase with a handful of shapefiles. The contents are likely to change often, so I want to build a tool that allows me to merge all the shapefiles in the GDB into one layer.

This is what I currently have: 
[image]

However, I am not expecting this to work, as it seems like it would just grab one file each iteration and 'merge' it with itself. Is there a workaround so that it grabs all files from the GDB to merge them? I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

Comment: Look at the answer by @Aaron his is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `arcpy` solution rather than a ModelBuilder one but I believe it is pretty straightforward. To run it you just have to open the Python console in ArcMap and paste the following lines:

```
import arcpy

# specify the path to your GDB
arcpy.env.workspace = 'path/name.gdb'

# get all the Feature Classes in the GDB
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# run the Merge tool
arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=fcs, output='merge_result')
```

This will create a feature class called **merge_result** in your GDB.

Comment: I have a Spyder environment set up with Arcpy. Unfortunately, I get the following error when running it:

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Input Datasets: Value is required
Failed to execute (Merge).


Also, when I do print(fcs) the output is 'None'. Any ideas?

Comment: It is possible that the path to your gdb is not correct. Can you show me how you declared the path?

Comment: The issue was '/' vs. '\' in declaring the path. Classic. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When declaring paths in Python make sure to use double backslash (`\\`) or put an `r` before your string to escape special sequences such as `\n` or `\t`.